# 'Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary ' encountered error after updating chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, binary

I've previously encountered error telling me that I need Chrome driver version 99 (which I downloaded and installed), then I encountered this error next. I tried adding setProperty with the location of my chromedriver but I still get the same error. I'm using Selenium Java. If you can send me a light, it would get me out of my stump. I've tried some links and forums but I'm still stuck. Thanks in advance, below is the exception:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

[image: console error]

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: newer ChromeDriver may need newer Chrome Browser.

Comment: what is your Chrome Browser version and Chrome driver version

Comment: This error usually comes when there in incompatibility between chrome browser and chrome driver